# Bluetooth development on windows

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, bluetooth

i need to create an application on a window machine that will communicate with a portable device over bluetooth...i am new to bluetooth so i was wondering what sort of APIs and drivers were available in the windows system...I know there is the bluez stack in Linux and OSX but not so much about the windows system.

and also i need to transfer this data into a web application...any suggestions on how i go about starting with this thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the library I maintain...  http://32feet.net :-)  We support the MSFT Bluetooth and Widcomm Bluetooth stacks on Win32.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the Bluetooth stack. Microsoft's stack is introduced in Windows XP Sp1 and is accessible using [Windows Wireless SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa362932(VS.85).aspx). Other Bluetooth stacks, many of them predate Xp Sp1, may require SDKs from the stack's provider.